# setError() does not show error on disabled edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to show error on a disabled edittext. The red error drawable shows up but as my edittext is disabled `edittet.setEnabled(false);`, there is now way to click it and hence the error popup does not show.

is there any other way to show error on a disabled edittext ?

Also is there any way to show an error on a spinner ? I am doing this :-

```
if(((Spinner) view).getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView)
   ((TextView)((Spinner) view).getChildAt(i)).setError("");
```

This shows the red error drawable but not the error

Comment: try to make the edit text enabled and see what happens. also can you post the code where you call the set error method

Comment: ono issues with enabled edittext. i want to show on a disabled

Comment: Can't you enable the edit text before setting the error?

Comment: Dude, you are not providing a solution. When it is enabled, i have no problem. I want it when it is disabled.Simple

Answer (score 1):

`requestfocus()` to the disabled edittext will do it

Comment: @KishanSolanki124 could you please post a code snippet. It will be helpful to resolve. Please try with focus() or requestfocus() over the disabled edittext both serve the same purpose. Thank you.

Comment: etEmail.error = context.getString(R.string.val_enter_email)
etEmail.requestFocus() where etEmail is edittext. But only icon is showing. error is not showing. Code is in Kotlin.

Comment: Am not completely aware of Kotlin. In Kotlin requestFocus is something like this I hope etEmail?.isFocusable.